# Suppose $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ be a product of distinct primes. Given $p_i-1\mid n-1$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, show that $n$ is a Carmichael number.

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ be a product of distinct primes. Given $p_i-1\mid n-1$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, show that $n$ is a Carmichael number.

This is a question on a past exam that I find difficulty to answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is really similar to your previous question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546156/suppose-k-is-an-integer-such-that-6k-1-12k-1-18k-1-are-primes-sho/546178#546178); and the approach to either question is the same.

Comment: Yes, I am getting more familiar with this kind of problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $a$ and $n$ be relatively prime. Then $p_i$ does not divide $a$. Thus by Fermat's Theorem we have $a^{p_i-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i}$, and therefore $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let, $c_i = \frac{n-1}{p_i-1}$. $c_i$ is an integer $\Leftarrow$ $p_i-1\mid n-1, $ for $i=1,2,…,k$.

$a^{c_i*(p_i-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i} \Leftarrow$ Fermat's little theorem

$\Rightarrow a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i}$ ------- (1)

(1) is true for $i = 1, 2, 3, ... k$. Therefore, it can be written as below,

$a^{(n-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ ------- (2)

Here, $n (= p_1p_2p_3 ... p_k)$ is a composite number.

Hence, according to (2), $n$ is a Carmichael number.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you. I have rendered the texts and equations.